# AWS CLI install with homebrew keep error with [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED]

Tags: python, macos, ssl, homebrew, aws-cli

My system is M1 Mac with macOS 12.3.1 and aws cli install via homebrew
when tried to run `aws s3 ls` it keep error with
`SSL validation failed for https://s3.{awsregion}.amazonaws.com/ [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1129)`

I've check python3 SSL path with command `python3 -c 'import ssl; print(ssl.get_default_verify_paths())'`
result is `DefaultVerifyPaths(cafile='/opt/homebrew/etc/openssl@1.1/cert.pem', capath=None, openssl_cafile_env='SSL_CERT_FILE', openssl_cafile='/opt/homebrew/etc/openssl@1.1/cert.pem', openssl_capath_env='SSL_CERT_DIR', openssl_capath='/opt/homebrew/etc/openssl@1.1/certs')`

which means it uses brew install version of openssl@1.1
and python3 also uses brew install version python@3.9 location is
`/opt/homebrew/bin/python3`

I've tried reinstalling awscli, openssl@1.1, and also python@3.9 then also tried to

1. Uninstall Python3 from brew
2. Install Python with the installer from Python website
3. Execute Install Certificates.command in the Python folder
4. Uninstall Python
5. Install python@3.9 from brew

also gave me the same error.

Here little information about my system

- M1 Mac - MacOS 12.3.1
- Python3 - brew python@3.9 (3.9.12)
- OpenSSL - brew openssl@1.1 (1.1.1n)
- AWS CLI - brew awscli (2.6.0)
- Xcode CLT - 13.3.1.0.1.1648687083
- Clang - 13.1.6 build 1316

Does anyone have any idea about this issue?  Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 7):

Set the AWS_CA_BUNDLE environmental variable to the cert.pem file from [Mozilla](https://curl.se/docs/caextract.html) (available in [formulae "ca-certificates"](https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/ca-certificates)) like so:

`export AWS_CA_BUNDLE=$HOMEBREW_PREFIX/etc/ca-certificates/cert.pem`

Comment: $HOMEBREW_PREFIX wasn't set for me, so I did:
export AWS_CA_BUNDLE=$(brew --prefix)/etc/ca-certificates/cert.pem

Comment: Good point. I use [Shell Completion](https://docs.brew.sh/Shell-Completion) to set.